# Intellij + Maven, re execute goal on MAKE PROJECT

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

```
<execution>
    <idassets-1</id>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <configuration>
      <tasks>

          <property name="compile_classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>

        <exec
          dir="/company/"
          executable="/company/Scripts/generate-sources.sh"
          failonerror="true">
          <arg line="${compile_classpath}" />
        </exec>
      </tasks>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

Which works fine when you **mvn install**. 
However, when you add a file to the project, or a recompile in Intellij, i would like for it **to execute again** in order to scan and regenerate sources.

I am not sure Intellij does this. Is there an Intellij goal that could force the execution of this once again?

I have also been experimenting with **ANT and generate-sources phase**, so if it is possible to do from there, that might also be fine.

Comment: right click on the project go to maven and the click on regenerate sources. you might need mvn plugin.

Comment: @StackFlowed Hmm, ok, seems to work, but that is a manual step. Is there a way to get that behaviour on make project ?

Comment: @momomo Do you want to add that step before you run your project as the `Make` does?

Comment: i think there is way to set it in project structure you have to look i don't have intellij on this machine

Comment: @nullpointer yes, before make is what I am looking for. Preferably multi developer / team developer friendly

Comment: @nullpointer sorry, i kind of misunderstood you question, not only before run. but before make is actually run, at whenever time, even after the application is already running.

Comment: *make is actually run, at whenever time, even after the application is already running.* do you mean to say when the IDE is running the `make` ?

Comment: @nullpointer before it runs the make. But the make can be initiated even when an application is already running, ie a web application. If you change a java class, add a file, you can, if you are using hotspot, jrebel or code reloading, you can get intellig to execute make, so not only once at startup of application. Do you know what I mean?